# How to check Bastion login logs in Azure to VM

Tags: azure, login, bastion

We share a domain admin account credential for one of our Active Directory VM stored in Azure. Users will connect to the VM via Bastion in Azure.

Currently someone disabled a user in the AD and we would like to check this login was done from whose Azure account. Is there a log that can we check on this Bastion sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Azure Activity log of the VM to see who started the session.

Comment: It only shows these 2 types of entries:

'audit Policy action' and 'Health Event Resolved'